# How to ignore mime type for maff file extension?

Tags: debian, firefox, mime-types, iceweasel

I have this [Mozilla Archive Format, with MHT and Faithful Save](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/) addon installed with Iceweasel on debian 8.3 jessie stable. The addon is useful in saving webpages into single file with extension **maff**.

The mimetype for this maff file is `application/zip`. Because of this, whenever I open maff file, it opens in `Archive Manager` or analogous application.

In order to open maff files in iceweasel, I have chosen `Open with` Iceweasel in file properties. Doing so opens maff files with iceweasel, but also opens every zip file in iceweasel with a download dialogue box. I think this is because the system has set mime type `application/zip` with iceweasel.

All I want is to open maff files with iceweasel/firefox and open zip files in regular Archive Manager. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/737495/339853).

Basically, what you have to do is create a `maff.xml` file in `/usr/share/mime/packages/` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/maff">
         <comment>Mozilla Archive Format</comment>
         <glob pattern="*.maff"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

and then run `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`.

This will add a separate MIME type for `.maff` files which would allow you to set file associations for it independently of other file types.